# Value changes while making an insert into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have my SQL statement like this:

```
select @constVal = FunctionWeight from dbo.FunctionWeights 
                      where FunctionWeights.FunctionName = 'MatchZIP';

 select @constVal as 'VALUE FROM LAST ZIP'    

 INSERT INTO #Temp2(RowNumber, ValFromFunc, FuncWeight, percentage)
             SELECT RowNumber, PercentMatch, @constVal, PercentMatch * @constVal
             from dbo.MatchZIP(@ZIP);

select * from #Temp2
```

**Output:**

```
VALUE FROM LAST ZIP
0.7

Rownumber   ValFromFunc FuncWeight  Percentage
81              100            1    100
82              100            1    100
83              100            1    100
84              100            1    100
```

**Problem:**

Value of `@constVal` is retrieved just right as expected. In `Insert` statement of #Temp2, I am inserting value of `@constVal` in `FuncWeight` column of #Temp2 table and what is inserted in FuncWeight column is `1` irrespective of what `@constVal` variable contains and I don't understand why is that happening at all.

I had doubt that it might be a `datatype` problem .But `datatype` of `FuncWeight` column in `Float(3)` and so should be able to hold it right.

Datatypes of  `#Temp2`

```
Rownumber int not null,
ValFromFunc float(3)null,
FuncWeight float(3) null,
Percentage float(3) null
```

Just for Info: @MatchFromZIP(@Zip) is a Table Valued Function and returns a table with two fields only which are inserted in `Rownumber` and `ValFromFunc` column.

Comment: i think you are .Once change all float to decimal(18,2). and thoroughly check each and every corner .Also float auto round off .

Comment: Float(3) is NOT a 3 digit float, however it SHOULD still work... As @KumarHarsh mentioned, replace all floats with decimals.

Comment: @KumarHarsh I tried your suggestion. It still does not work and gives 1.0000

Comment: @RhysJones : I replaced all floats with decimal(18,4) and yet it does not work and gives 1.0000 in FuncWeight column

Comment: @RhysJones: Edited the question.Could you please check

Comment: Can you add the variable declaration for @ConstVal, the table definition of #Temp2 and the returned table_type_definition for the dbo.MatchZip function to your question please.

Comment: From visible script.you need tocheck datatype of @ConstVal,datetype of #Temp2 's columns and above all datatype of dbo.MatchZIP.For testing,put only this script in new query window .Lastly you can also check if any trigger or constraint doing the trick .